# Заместитель Генерального директора

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать в сокращенном виде: заместитель генерального директора

Answer (score 1):

> § 196. Названия должностей, званий,
> титулов пишутся со строчной буквы,
> напр.: президент, канцлер,
> председатель, министр,
> премьер-министр, заместитель министра,
> мэр, император, королева, хан, шейх,
> генеральный секретарь, заслуженный
> деятель культуры, лауреат Нобелевской
> премии, посол, атташе, директор,
> генеральный директор, академик, доктор
> наук, профессор, член-корреспондент,
> генерал-майор, командующий войсками,
> руководитель департамента, заведующий
> отделом, управляющий делами. В
> официальных текстах названия высших
> государственных должностей и титулов
> пишутся с прописной буквы, напр.:
> Президент Российской Федерации,
> Председатель Правительства РФ,
> Председатель Государственной думы,
> Премьер-министр Индии, Её Величество
> Королева Англии (см. также § 202).
> Однако в неофициальных текстах эти
> названия пишутся со строчной буквы,
> напр.: выборы президента, выступление
> председателя Госдумы, распоряжение
> премьер-министра, приём у королевы.

Из этого следует, что все буквы в любом случае должны быть строчные. С прописной пишутся только названия *высших* государственных должностей. И то только в официальных текстах.

Относительно сокращения можно сказать только то, что стандартное сокращение есть только для слова "заместитель" - "зам.". А генерального директора можно сокращать, как угодно, руководствуясь общим правилом: читающему должно быть понятно и не должно быть разночтений.

Я бы сократил до "зам. гендиректора".

Comment: Shamov, Вы читаете хотя бы то, что цитируете?
Где там вообще пункт о сокращениях?
И после этого делать столь обязывающий вывод о строчных буквах?

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, автор вопроса и без меня знает, что обычные должности пишутся со строчной буквы. Процитировать параграф на эту тему мне пришлось только потому, что вы уже успели дать неправильный ответ, который мог сбить его с толку. Если бы вы молчали в тех случаях, когда не знаете правильного ответа, то мне не пришлось бы цитировать.

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, Вы задались целью троллить если не форум, то меня лично.
Автор однозначно спрашивает, как писать сокращение. Подобные вопросы неоднократно обсуждались, как любительница посылать "поискать в интернте", Ваша Голословность вполне могла это сама обнаружить, прежде чем формулировать мнение, чего хотел автор и чей ответ неправильный.

Comment: Моя цель в том, чтобы лично вы меня не комментировали. Просто перестаньте флудить и неправильно отвечать на вопросы.

Comment: А моя цель в том, чтобы вы престали указывать, кому и что делать.
Кто вы такой в конце концов каждый раз единолично решать, кто прав, а кто нет?

Comment: Я не пытаюсь решать, кто прав. Просто хочу, чтобы вы не мешали мне давать ответы, засоряя комментарии своим флудом. В своих ответах отвечайте, что угодно. В тех случаях, когда это будет уместно, я буду просто давать обоснованное опровержение в своём ответе. Комментарии не предназначены для дискуссий.

Comment: Я обещаю вам комменетировать каждый ваш ответ, если сочту это нужным. 
Если не хотите дискуссий, можете не отвечать на комментарии.
Но если уж отвечаете, так давайте действительно обоснованное опровержение (а не такое, как всегда). Как только такое произойдет, немедленно прекращу столь неприятный вам разговор.

Comment: В данном случае моё опровержение было обоснованным.

Answer (score 0):

В сокращенном виде в особо официальных бумагах лучше не писать.

В менее официальных (письмах, справках и проч.), если уж никак нельзя иначе, сокращайте по своему разумению, нормативных рекомендаций на этот счет нет. "Зам. Гендиректора", например. В отношении строчной-заглавной в сокращении "зам" можно спорить. Если это должность такая, то, наверное, возможна и заглавная.

Comment: >В данном случае моё опровержение было обоснованным.
(shamov)

В данном случае его вообще не было. 
Вы даже не сформулировали, что именно вы собрались опровергать - и на основании чего. Во всяком случае темы вопрос это не касается.
Вот я вам совершенно четко сказал, что автор спрашивает о сокращениях, а ваша цитата упоминаний о них не содержит.